# What is $ArrayType$16008 in >net Reflector?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflector

I'm reflecting a c# dll and I see an internal static readonly `$ArrayType$16008` can someone tell me what this?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=16008, Pack=1)]
public struct $ArrayType$16008
{
}
```

Did the compiler generate it? Or is it a UserDefined type that reflector can't see?

Comment: given the appearance of '16008' I'd say generated by reflector .... beyond that I'm not sure we should help you decompile a DLL if it's not yours....

Comment: When you initialize a large enough array with static data (a byte[] for example), the C# compiler will generate a type of that size and use an instance of that type to initialize the array, using System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray(). Probably because it's faster than to init the array element by element. It might be one of those types you're seeing.

Comment: I vaguely remember the C++/CLI compiler generating such types.

Answer (score 0):

As the commentors say. The compiler generated it.

Whenever you see a dollar sign used outside a string, in reversed engineered c#-code, you can be quite sure, it's compiler generated.